# How to use DNS instead of /etc/hosts?

Tags: 14.04, networking, dns

In `/etc/hosts`, I can for example input

```
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Now I have a nameserver (pdns with postgre-backend), which I want to use in the intranet.

So, I tell my dns server, that `example.com` is, for example, `192.168.1.24`

Assuming the DNS server runs on 192.168.1.64, how can I replace `/etc/hosts` with my nameserver ?

That is to say, it should resolve example.com to 192.168.1.2 (using the DNS on 192.168.1.24), but any other domain that I did not overwrite locally should be resolved to its real IP, using whatever is used by default.

Where do I have to put this in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: Comment out the entry from `/etc/hosts`, since it has priority over entries from DNS.

Comment: @muru: That much is clear...

Comment: @muru does `/etc/hosts` priority can be set in nsswitch?

Comment: @AizuddinZali Yes, but not for a single site. Just move `dns` before `files`

Comment: @muru, ok make sense he only want single site.